# How can I extract column number from java exception

Tags: java, exception

When the JVM throws and compilation error it prints out something like this in the console

```
Error on line 3 in /Main.java:3: error: ';' expected
System.out.print("Hello")
                         ^
```

When throwing an Exception I am aware that I can get the line number from

`e.getStackTrace()[0].getLineNumber());`

inside a try catch where `e` is an Exception

but is there a way to get the column, so far I parse Errors with a regex looking for index of `^` on the third line. but have no way of figuring it out in case of an Exception.

Comment: Are you aware that compilation error is different from runtime exception? The thing it is printed in your first block is compilation error whereas you're trying to capture runtime exception. Please be clear.

Comment: Maybe you can use something like this:
http://www.saxproject.org/apidoc/org/xml/sax/SAXParseException.html

Comment: I meant an exception, I got used to scripting languages ^^;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, what you are seeing above is the message of a compilation error. A runtime exception does not carry that information.